# Find the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x^2 - 1}{ \ln(x)} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I tried substituting $\ln (x)$ as $t$, but it led to no standard integral for me to move further.

Substituting $\ln (x)$ as $-t$ gives
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-3t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$

Comment: This is what Robert Z did. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @robjohn because it's not an elementary integral. It's a special integral and I'm pretty sure they didn't teach me that for high school

Comment: The Frullani integral only uses that $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $e^x$ is continuous at $x=0$. I will add an answer that expands on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: for $a>0$, write $$f(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^a-1}{\ln x} dx$$
Then we can differentiate with respect to $a$ to give $f'(a) = 1/(a+1)$. Also note that $$\lim_{a\to 0^+} f(a) = 0$$ This can help you to find the integration constant.

Comment: Hmm I have never seen this kind of method before. What is this called? We introduced a new variable.. when can I use this?

Comment: It is called "differentiation under the integral", there are some examples in wikipedia.

Comment: @Harsha G. Take a look at [this article](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf) Example 3.1 will be your integral.

Comment: read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505423/evaluation-of-int-01-fracx2015-1-ln-xdx and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017018/how-to-integrate-int-01-fracx7-1-logxdx and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239530/using-feymanns-trick-in-advanced-integration

Answer (score 6):

In general, for $a>-1$, by letting $t=-\ln(x)$, we obtain 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^a-1}{\ln x} dx=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-(a+1)t}}{t} dt=\ln(a+1)$$
where in the last step we used a known result about [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) with $f(t)=e^{-t}$.

Comment: How do you know that the integral converges? Or can we always use the formula when it gives a real number? Also, can we generalize to more $a$ than $a>0$? $\ln(a+1)$ is still a real number if $a>-1$.

Comment: [It seems that according to this paper given in another comment, $a>-1$ may also be possible (see Example 3.1.).](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf)

Comment: @user263326 Yes, you are right, it converges for $a>-1$. In fact, near $0^+$ the integrand is $\sim 1/(x^{-a}\ln(x)$ whose integral is convergent when $-a<1$.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2} - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x & =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x + 1}\
\overbrace{{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}^{\ds{= \int_{0}^{1}x^{t}\,\dd t}}\
\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{t + 1} + x^{t}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{{1 \over t + 2} + {1 \over t + 1}}\,\dd t =
\bracks{\ln\pars{3} - \ln\pars{2}} + \ln\pars{2}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\ln\pars{3}} \approx 1.099
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) Clever, but does require noticing the fact about $\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}$

Comment: @Isham Thanks. $\substack{@\quad @ \\  \mid\\ \smile}$.

Comment: @robjohn Integrals $\int_{0}^{1}x^{t}t^{n}\,\mathrm{d}t$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t}t^{n}\,\mathrm{d}t$ yield interesting identities for suitable values of $n$ and $x$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Robert Z's answer,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^2-1}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2x}-1}{x}\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{x}\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-3x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-3x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{3\epsilon}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^{3\epsilon}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_1^3\frac{e^{-\epsilon x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_1^3\left(\frac1x+\frac{o(\epsilon)}x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_1^3\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x+o(\epsilon)\right)\\
&=\int_1^3\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&=\log(3)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The antiderivative is not elementary: $F(x) = \text{Ei}(1,  -\ln(x)) - \text{Ei}(1,-3 \ln(x))$, where $$\text{Ei}(1,z) = \int_1^\infty e^{-tz} t^{-1}\; dt $$

As $x \to 0+$, $-\ln(x) \to +\infty$ and both $\text{Ei}(1,  -\ln(x))$ and $\text{Ei}(1,-3 \ln(x))$ go to $0$.  As $x \to 1-$, both
$\text{Ei}(1,-\ln(x))$ and $\text{Ei}(1,-3 \ln(x)) \to \infty$, but 
$$\text{Ei}(1, 1/s) \sim \ln(s) -\gamma + O(1/s)$$
resulting in $\text{Ei}(1,-\ln(x)) - \text{Ei}(1,-3 \ln(x)) = \ln(3) + O(\ln(x))$.
Thus the answer is $\ln(3)$.